# Caddy V2 and Load balancing or just kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, high-availability, caddy

I'm a freshman CS student and don't have much experience with topics such as load-balancing, so I hope someone can guide me to the right track.

My planned setup is 2 webservers with docker (standalone instances.. if not necessary not as a cluster).

These two servers would all have the same running containers and a caddy web server with the same mounted config on both caddy instances.

How can I make a layer above which redirect's the client to the server which is available?

Or is my planned setup nonsense and I should learn Kubernetes...

Comment: That setup seems fine; there's no rule that you use Kubernetes or other clustering software just because you have more than one system.  Remember that most of the modern Internet grew up before there were Docker containers, and there are general-purpose system management tools (Salt Stack, Ansible, Chef, ...) that can deploy an identical setup to multiple systems.  Is there a more specific programming-related problem you're running into?

Comment: You can use client side load balancing. Basically the load metrics are real time exported from Caddy to a central system which real time an aggregate summary to all clients.    The client are pushed any changes and can then make intelligent decisions about how they route their requests.



This takes the load off the load balancing server, as it is no longer in the Data Plane.




Topology:
Caddy ( with netdata metrics plugin ) --> timescle DB ( runs in top of Postresql ) --> Client push over SSE, WS or WebTransport.

Answer (score 0):

Should you go the Kubernetes route, you could still use Caddy with [`caddyserver/ingress`](https://github.com/caddyserver/ingress)

It would provide a caddy-based [ingress service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), which would:

- create a service of [type `LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) in the `caddy-system` namespace on your cluster
- provide automatic HTTPS certificates for all hostnames defined in ingress resources that it is managing.